# I currently am learning jquery and I am unable to get it to work on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery

ultimately like my html to point to a file which contains either the jquery compressed or uncompressed source code which I have downloaded from the jquery site so that I am able to use the jquery scripts. I very new to programming so please excuse my poor coding structure. you may either find my code by following this link https://repl.it/H8eo/25 or by going 
http://felipeiscoding.com/main/HTML_Files/jqueryTesting.html

and looking at the existing source code here.

> > bad code here >>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.compressed.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->

        <style>
            body {
                background-color: black;
            }

            #square {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            $(document)
                .ready(function () {
                    alert("Im working!");
                });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="square">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (typeof jquery == "undefined") {
                alert("Jquery is not installed");
            } else {
                alert("Jquery is installed correctly");
            }
        </script>



    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add an actual question with a problem description.

Comment: https://repl.it/H8eo/26 use a jquery `src` on the script that actually exists and check `jQuery` instead of `jquery`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: When I load you linked page and open the network tool I see that your attempt to download jquery from your server results in a 404 not found. Make sure you have the file name spelled correctly and you put it in the place you specify in your script tag.

Comment: I have checked the url 'http://felipeiscoding.com/main/HTML_Files/jqueryTesting.html' and did't find any issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the console you can see 
    https://replit.org/data/web_project/2d978b375b293a397e1c8c0898c77572/jquery-3.2.1.compressed.js

fails to load.  So it's not working because jquery isn't loaded.

Comment: I'm glad someone knows this without having to run it- i took that part out.

Comment: You were right that was a mistake, I saw the 404 error on the console.
I changed the code slightly so that it does not prompt me with the 404 error, yet I am still not able to run jquery on my website.
Would anyone know why something like this would be happening?

here is my new code.
>>
the code has been changed as shown in the following link:

view-source:http://www.felipeiscoding.com/main/HTML_Files/jqueryTesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `typeof jquery` you need to use `window.jQuery`

```js
if (!window.jQuery) {
  alert("Jquery is not installed");
} else {
  alert("Jquery is installed correctly");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Im working!");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: You're conflating two things: (1) `jquery` vs. `jQuery`, and (2) `typeof something` vs. `window.something`. In the OP's code, the issue isn't whether `window.` is used or not. It isn't necessary to do it that way when you're using `typeof`, although it would be if you were just doing `if(jQuery)`. The latter would fail in a bad way if `jQuery` were not defined, but `typeof` as used in the question is fine. The only issue in this part of OP's code is the miscapitalization of `jQuery`.